# how to align asp.net label text in center

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a label with in a div in ASP.NET just before a text box but I am not sure how can I center align my asp.net label,

```
    <div style="float: left; width: 65%;">
        <asp:Label ID="lba" CssClass="aa" runat="server" Text="aaa" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the `div` element add style `text-align: center` to center the text

`<div style="float: left; width: 65%; text-align: center;">`

Comment: No this wont work if the label is inside a table cell. You would need to use <td style="text-align: center">. But that will also centre the label and the text inside the label, inside the cell. So be careful

Comment: My Answer is for OP's question. Off-course, if your are using `<td>` or any `tag` then you need to use `text-align: center`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="float: left; width: 65%; text-align: center;">
      <asp:Label ID="lba" CssClass="aa" runat="server" Text="aaa" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="text-align:center; width:100%;"> 
  <asp:Lable ID="lba" style="margin:0 auto;" CssClass="aa" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

you can also try style="margin:0 auto;" to label and width 100% to parend div.

Comment: Not related to question. -1